# When to use Apache Ignite?

Tags: .net, ignite, data-caching

I am working in a project where I was suggested that data caching might be useful.

I came across Apache Ignite but I am unable to understand if it is in fact just and in memory store or is it a layer above the database.
If there is any clear explanation of how to integrate this into a .Net web application, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Ignite is a distributed in-memory platform. It provides a transactional key-value storage as well as compute capabilities and other features. Generally it resides between applications and data sources (having the external data source is optional though).

To integrate with a .NET application simply run an embedded node using `Ignition.Start()` method. You can then add as many standalone nodes as you like to scale out.

Refer to this documentation for more info: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/getting-started-1

Comment: That's what I read but I couldn't figure out how does the data the database (the data source) stay in sync with the cache? Is there any database interaction that I am missing out reading on?

Comment: @NikhilGirraj Cache talks to database through `ICacheStore` interface. See this page for details: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/persistent-store

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ignite as a read-through / write-through cache.

Have a look at these pages:

https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/caching/database-caching.html
https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/persistent-store